# Nginx Ingress Controller does not set X-Forwarded-Host

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have setup the Nginx Ingress Controller with my microservice; this microservice uses Hateoas to produce the links; I have the following Ingress set.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "server: imemywork";
    nginx.org/ssl-services: "mic-ser-service"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "1024m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /service(|/)(.*) {
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host/service;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
      }
  name: mic-ser-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - imemywork.com
      secretName: mic-ser-tls-certificate
  rules:
    - host: api.imemywork.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /service(|/)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: mic-ser-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

None of X-Forwarded-* headers get set on the request; Since these are not set, the HATEOAS links are using http and the host sent by browser to produce links; Am I setting them in wrong place? I also tried to move the location block to under configuration-snippet with no luck; Is there anything else, I need to set/enable in Nginx Ingress controller?

Bts, having more_set_header under configuration-snippet only adds the headers to the response, not on the request to the server.

Comment: did you try configuration-snippet instead of server-snippet? https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet

Check if the contents of the annotation are present in the nginx.conf file using: 
´kubectl exec nginx-ingress-controller-873061567-4n3k2 -n kube-system cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf´

Comment: @Tech Junkie, do you still have an issue? Did you try Matthias advise?

Comment: I did try and found that nginx.conf is not getting updated.

Comment: Have you tried to reload config file using `sudo nginx -s reload`? Also are you using any ConfigMap?

Answer (score 0):

I think x-forwaded-* headers get set by default in the ingress-nginx. You may want to update the x-forwarded-proto header to "https" when it reaches to your application. Unfortunately, there is no standard annoatation available at the moment in ingress to override the x-forwarded-* headers. However, there is a work around available to resolve this issue.

You can write your custom ingress plugin which will take care of rewriting the x-forwarded-* headers. As stated in [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6358#issuecomment-722351158)

> Changing the value of the header X-Forwarded-Port without using a
> custom template can be done with a plugin.
> https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/plugins
>
> ```
> local ngx = ngx
>
> local _M = {}
>
> function _M.rewrite()
>   if ngx.var.http_cf_connecting_ip then
>     ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Changing x-forwarded-port to 443")
>     ngx.var.pass_port = 443
>   end
> end
>
> return _M
> ```
>
> The condition to change the variable can check for any other header
> (like limiting the change to a particular host) Using a configmap is
> possible to mount the plugin as a file
> https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L396-L404